# Variable assignment in batch

Tags: variables, batch-file

This question seems to be (very) stupid be I can't deal with it :(

When I tried this batch code:

```
if "%1" == "-i" (
set is = %2
echo. %is%
shift
)
```

called with 2 (or more) arguments, it does NOT work. It actually prints a blank. The "shift" command is not done either. When I watch the executed code (without the @echo off at the beginning), I can see that the "set" command is completed.

What's wrong with it?

Example of calling:

```
c:\script.bat -i test -d bla
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You have two issues. By default group of statements in parens will have variable expansion done all at once, that is before your `set` command. Also the semantics for `set` is wrong, you don't want spaces around the `=`.

Add this to the top of your file:

```
setlocal ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION
```

and remove the spaces around `=` in `set`:

```
set is=%2
```

Finally used delayed expansion:

```
echo. !is!
```

A possible third issue is you may need two `SHIFT`s, one for `-i`, one for it's `is` argument.

### Update

Thanks to @dbenham for pointing out that it wasn't a syntax error with `set`, it's just surprising behavior that deserves a little explanation.  If you execute these commands:

```
set a=one
echo "%a%"
```

The result is:

```
"one"
```

That makes sense, but try:

```
set b = two
echo "%b%"
```

And you get:

```
"%b%"
```

What? This is what you would expect when environment var `b` is unset. But we *just* set it. Or did we:

```
echo "%b %"
```

Displays:

```
" two"
```

For the Windows `set` command, unlike any other language or environment I'm aware of, the spaces are significant. The spaces before the `=` become part of the environment var name, spaces after become part of the value. This uncommon behavior is a common source of errors when writing Windows batch programs.

Comment: I upvoted, but technically the OP's SET syntax is not wrong, just not what is wanted :-) The OP's code will create a variable with a trailing space in the name and a leading space in the value.

Comment: @dbenham, I didn't say it was a syntax error. It's apparently a logic error because he later references the var without the space.

Comment: Your 3rd sentence: *"Also your syntax for set is wrong..."* Relax, I upvoted because I think your answer is good. I'm just being pedantic.

Comment: Oops, you're correct. I'll fix it when I'm at a keyboard (I'm mobile now). Thanks.

Comment: @dbenham, fixed (and added section describing `set` behavior). Thanks for the correction. Sorry I didn't understand the first time.

Comment: @el_grom, on my system I seem to need to use `!` to get delayed variable expansion, not `%`. Make sure your not picking up the value of `%is%` from a previous test run (make sure it's value is different and correct).

Comment: Thanks for the 'set' explanation and the tip! I'll check that right now. I didn't know that 'set' was so "sensitive"... Good to know! Thanks :)