# Cannot set variable from %% value inside batch script

Tags: windows, batch-file

Based from this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44929240/6003691) I am trying to save the `%%a` and `%%b` values into variables but it does not work:

```
@ECHO OFF
SETLOCAL
set "path_of_folder=C:\folderA\folderB"

if exist "%path_of_folder%" ( 
  echo Path exists.
  for /f "skip=5 tokens=1,2,4 delims= " %%a in (
   'dir /ad /tc "%path_of_folder%\."') do IF "%%c"=="." (
    set "dt=%%a"
    echo Created on: %%a, %%b
    set "vara=%%a"
    set "varb=%%b"
    echo %vara%, %varb%

    REM substring
    set day=%vara:~0,2%
  )
) else ( 
  echo Path does not exist. 
)

GOTO :EOF
```

But the output of the `echo %vara%, %varb%` is empty even though the previous `echo Created on: %%a, %%b` prints the correct information!. The idea is that I can manipulate that variable afterwards for example for extracting substrings.

After searching online, I found this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13797629/variable-assignment-in-batch) from which I tried the `setlocal ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION`, and the approach with the exclamation marks, but they too failed.

[UPDATE to include my other attempt and partly fix when using exclamation marks]

```
@ECHO OFF
SETLOCAL ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION
set "path_of_folder=C:\folderA\folderB"

if exist "%path_of_folder%" ( 
  echo Path exists.
  for /f "skip=5 tokens=1,2,4 delims= " %%a in (
   'dir /ad /tc "%path_of_folder%\."') do IF "%%c"=="." (
    set "dt=%%a"
    echo Created on: %%a, %%b
    set vara=%%a
    set varb=%%b
    echo !vara!, !varb!

    REM substring
    set day=%vara:~0,2%
  )
) else ( 
  echo Path does not exist. 
)

GOTO :EOF
```

Where the `vara` and `varb` are now saved and echoed appropriately but the substring now does not work..

I tried reading more about the specifics of a `%%` variable ([link](https://superuser.com/questions/670992/what-does-the-percent-sign-and-in-a-batch-file-argument-mean)) but that did not help me either.

Any suggestions/examples please?

Comment: Show us your ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION attempt.

Comment: @Anders I included the other attempt as you requested along with a minor fix for saving the variables as the should however they are not 'properly' saved since the following substring attempt does not work (i.e. returns nothing).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your 2nd script works perfectly. The only error I can spot is in this line: `set day=%vara:~0,2%`. It should be `set day=!vara:~0,2!`.

[image]

```
@ECHO OFF
SETLOCAL ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION
set "path_of_folder=C:\folderA\folderB"

if exist "%path_of_folder%" ( 
  echo Path exists.
  for /f "skip=5 tokens=1,2,4 delims= " %%a in (
   'dir /ad /tc "%path_of_folder%\."') do IF "%%c"=="." (
    set "dt=%%a"
    echo Created on: %%a, %%b
    set vara=%%a
    set varb=%%b
    echo !vara!, !varb!

    REM substring
    set day=!vara:~0,2!
  )
) else ( 
  echo Path does not exist. 
)
```

Comment: I was echoing the `day` using the `%` instead of `!`... 
Thank you for your answer. Could you please also provide a short explanation of why the `%%` requires `!`?

Comment: Take a look at this: https://ss64.com/nt/delayedexpansion.html This should explain everything.